# AppleScript : Set do script result as variable

Tags: safari, applescript, command-line

I would like to get the result of this search and display the result in a notification or safari popup.

" set result to do shell script "curl https://www.binlist.net/json/" & cc without altering line endings" only have as a result the same value of the main query

```
-- Web site https://www.binlist.net
-- Get https://www.binlist.net/json/431940
set cc to the clipboard
set finalresult to do shell script "curl https://www.binlist.net/json/" & cc without altering line endings
set the clipboard to finalresult

display notification "result is " & finalresult
```

The result won't display as a notification so for now, its only set as clipboard
Also the result is really raw can I clean that somehow ?

```
{\"bin\":\"431940\",\"brand\":\"VISA\",\"sub_brand\":\"\",\"country_code\":\"IE\",\"country_name\":\"Ireland\",\"bank\":\"BANK OF IRELAND\",\"card_type\":\"DEBIT\",\"card_category\":\"\",\"latitude\":\"53\",\"longitude\":\"-8\",\"query_time\":\"1.370709ms\"}""
```

Thanks.

Comment: Given your example JSON, what would you like to see displayed?

Comment: I just ran your code with having set `431940` on the clipboard and the `final result` set back to the clipboard was exactly what I see if looking at https://www.binlist.net/json/431940 in Safari.  So not sure what your issue is with formatting other the the results displayed in Script Editor e.g `set the clipboard to "{\"bin\":\"431940\...` the backslashes show there are not on the clipboard.  Are you saying they are?

Comment: Here is my result, I was wondering can I just keep "Visa" and "Ireland" and display in a notification : {"bin":"431940","brand":"VISA","sub_brand":"","country_code":"IE","country_name":"Ireland","bank":"BANK OF IRELAND","card_type":"DEBIT","card_category":"","latitude":"53","longitude":"-8","query_time":"651.384µs"}

Comment: Sorry but it is not clear, to me anyway, what you're asking in the last comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the **brand** and the **country_name** from the `JSON` data, you can use a JSON parser.

Here is an example of parsing `JSON` in `python`

```
-- Get https://www.binlist.net/json/431940
set cc to the clipboard as string
set finalresult to do shell script "curl https://www.binlist.net/json/" & cc & "  |  /usr/bin/python -c 'import json, sys; obj=json.load(sys.stdin); print obj[\"brand\"],obj[\"country_name\"]' "
display notification "Result is " & finalresult --> "Result is VISA Ireland"
```